# const char pointer declaration in struct

Tags: c++, struct, const-char

I'm trying to do this, but my compiler won't let me:

```
    struct {
        const char* string = "some text";
    } myAnonymousStruct;
```

I believe it's because no assignments can be made in a struct declaration - they're supposed to be made in functions or otherwise. But am I really not even allowed to assign `const char*` variables?
If anyone can let me know what I'm missing, I'd really appreciate it. thx

Comment: Put it into an initializer instead. FWIW, that's valid in C++11.

Comment: Where do I put an initialization list for an anonymous struct?

Comment: I don't think you can. The only way I know of to keep both is to use C++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is [perfectly fine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) on compilers that support C++11 or later.

Before C++11, members of a struct could not be default initialized. Instead they must be initialized after an instance struct is created.

If it fits your needs, you could use aggregate initialization like so:

```
struct {
    const char* string;
} myAnonymousStruct = { "some text" };
```

But if you're trying to default initialize more than just the one instance of the struct then you may want to give your struct a constructor and initialize members in it instead.

```
struct MyStruct {
    const char* str;
    MyStruct() : str("some text") { }
};

MyStruct foo;
MyStruct bar;
```

In the previous example, `foo` and `bar` are different instances of `MyStruct`, both with `str` initialized to `"some text"`.

Comment: I forgot about the option of aggregate initialization. Good thinking on that. However, the class vs. struct point is a bit irrelevant. You can put a constructor in a `struct` if you wish.

Comment: Wow! It worked. I've never seen that syntax before. I'll have to look into it. thx. I read what you said about using classes for large structs, but I should be fine with this since my struct only has two members.

Comment: @chris Good point! I've edited my answer to make note of this. Personally, when I start thinking of constructors, I go straight for classes.